# Reading a text file in scala, one line after the other, not iterated

Tags: scala, io

I'm trying to open a text file with Scala, read the first line, then the second, then the third.

All samples I've found online want to read/buffer the entire file into a list or array and then access the individual lines from that construct.

---

This code doesn't work as described above(of course). 
It reads the entire file into "first" since "file" is a BufferedStream and getLines fetches all lines, as it should.

```
import scala.io.Source;
object ScalaDemo {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val file = io.Source.fromFile("TextFile.txt");

    // -----------------------------------------------
    // read text from file, line by line, no iterator
    // -----------------------------------------------
    val first    = file.getLines().mkString;
    val second   = file.getLines().mkString; 
    val third    = file.getLines().mkString; 

    // Close the file   
    file.close;

    println(first+"|"+second+"|"+third); 
    }
}
```

What idiom/function can I use to read one line at a time... without using a list/array as an intermediate step.

Comment: Reading 3 lines without ever checking for error (in particular the file might have less than 3 lines) is not really safe, but if you're OK with having no error checking, you can just do `val lines = file.getLines(); val first,second,third = lines.next`

Comment: What is your problem ? gelLines returns an iterator, so you just have to iterate.  Your code is wrong because you use mkString, which transform a whole Seq into just one string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments, `.mkString` will fetch all the elements that the iterator would return and concatenate them in a single string.

The option of [@Régis Jean-Gilles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1632462/r%C3%A9gis-jean-gilles) is probably the best if you already know that you always have at least three lines in the file.

Another option is to call `getLines()` followed by `grouped(3)` to get an iterator that groups elements into blocks of 3. A call to `next()` will give you a list with at most three elements (it can have less if the iterator has only two elements left to return for example).

```
val ite = io.Source.fromFile("textfile.txt").getLines().grouped(3)

//list with the first three elements, if any -  
//otherwise an empty list if the file is empty
val list = if(ite.hasNext()) ite.next() else Nil
```

At least it does ensure that you won't have a `NoSuchElementException` at runtime if there is less than 3 lines in the file.

Comment: can I call this as val ite = io.Source.fromFile("textfile.txt").getLines().grouped(1) and then use the hasNext/next methods to read line by line?

Comment: @lexu You don't need `grouped(1)` to read line by line. It's kind of a no-op.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should also properly close the file after reading to release the resources. Below is the code you are looking for :

```
import scala.io.Source

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

var itr = Source.fromFile("input.txt")
var buffer = itr.getLines()

var line1 = buffer.next()
var line2 = buffer.next()
var line3 = buffer.next()
var line4 = buffer.next()

println("line1 "+line1+" \nline2 "+line2+" \nline3 "+line3+" \nline4 "+line4)

itr.close()
}
```

Comment: The example code provided in this 2-year old question already _does_ close the file. You have missed the point of the question and not offered an answer that is useful.